# query to select a specified number of rows

Tags: sql

Imagine a simple query:

```
SELECT name, lastname FROM people
```

Let's imagine it returns 6 rows. What i need to do is to return a number of rows that ROWS Mod 4 would be equal to 0. So if the query would normally return 6 rows, it should return 2 more rows with NULL for name and lastname. It's easy to count the rows it would return and generate the necessary union selects, but i'm wondering if it's possible to do in sql. I know, sounds kinda stupid and you're probably thinking about telling me to find a different solution, but that's the easiest workaround for my problem ;]

Comment: Could you describe your problem in order to reach another solution?

Comment: The one you already provided an answer to. MSSQL. Thank you, i'll try that

Answer (score 2):

for oracle:

```
SELECT name, lastname FROM people
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL FROM people
WHERE RowNum <= (Select mod(Count(*),4) from people)
```

for mssql: (>=2005)

```
SELECT name, lastname FROM people
UNION ALL
select null, null from
(
  SELECT row_number() over(order by name) r FROM people
)
WHERE r <= (Select Count(*) % 4 from people)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my mssql gives an error of incorrect syntax near 'where'. Anyway, i've just looked at my query and it's too complex for me to turn it into this. It'll become unreadable with all those joins and where statements. I guess i'll just add the necessary unions to sql programmatically. Thanks for the help!